# Overwrite TCEFORM from Extension Flexform

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I'm using TYPO3 8.7.1 and want to overwrite a flexform field with TCEFORM in PageTS.

The file locallang_db.xlf has the following entry:

```
<trans-unit id="section.title" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
  <source>Section</source><target state="translated">Title</target>
</trans-unit>
```

The following snippet is from my flexform file:

```
<numIndex index="1" type="array">
  <numIndex index="0">LLL:EXT:h_test/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:section.title</numIndex>
  <numIndex index="1">value</numIndex>
</numIndex>
```

I've now tried different variations to overwrite this:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.tx_htest.section.title = New Title
```

Or this:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.h_test.section.title = New Title
```

And much more, but none is working. Any help or hint is really appreciated!

Comment: I think it would help if this question contained more of the flexform, where you can also see the field name.

Answer (score 2):

You must include the sheetname of the flexform you want to override. See the [TSConfig reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TCEform/Index.html) for more details.

The next examples show, how to override flexform labels for the TYPO3 extension `sf_event_mgt` and the plugin `Pievent`. Note, that the **dataStructKey** is a combination of the extension key and the pluginname (in this example `sfeventmgt_pievent`)

**Example 1 - override label for field `switchableControllerActions`**

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.sfeventmgt_pievent.sDEF.switchableControllerActions.label = Overwritten Label
```

**Example 2 - override label for field `settings.queryLimit`**

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.sfeventmgt_pievent.sDEF.settings\.queryLimit.label = Overwritten Label
```

If the field to override includes a dot, the dot must be escaped with a `\` as shown in example 2.

Comment: Thank's for that. I've seen that, but couldn't find any information about the sheet_name. What is the sheetname?

Comment: Usually the default sheetname is `sDEF`, but this may vary depending on the structure of your Flexform.

Comment: ok. that's the sheetname of my flexform. my structure is still not working. is there some sort of "object browser" to find out the exact "path"?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Maybe your *dataStructKey* is wrong. What is your extension key and Plugin name? If your extension key is `h_test`, then the first part of the *dataStructKey* is `htest_` followed by your pluginname (all lowercase)

Comment: Thanks for ur help. i really appreciate it. The Plugin comes from a other extension called gridelements (tx_gridelements). I am sure u know it. The Plugin name should be "gridelements_pi1". So the dataStructKey is htest_gridelementspi1?

Comment: So you want to override a Label in the gridelements extension?

Comment: I've created a extension to extend the gridelements. So do I probably need to address gridelements even if the flexform comes from my extension, because i'm extending gridelements? To be hones that's something I haven't tried yet. That would be "TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.gridelements_gridelementspi1.sDEF.section.title = New Title" then?

Comment: Yes, I think you have to modify the Flexform from Gridelements directly. Please try the following: `TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.gridelements_pi1‌​.sDEF.section.title = New Title`

Note, that `gridelements` is the extension key and `pi1` the pluginname

Answer (score 0):

*Being late to answer this question, but I think there are some missing pieces ...*

---

While the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44605348/2444812) makes a good point about adding the Flexform sheet name and escaping dots in the Flexform field name, I think this is not the only problem.

I think the OP wants to override a language label, used within a list of items.

##### Example 1: Override an item in a non-flexform TCA example

I first show a **non-flexform TCA** example, because it is simple and you can go from there. You can first test that this works and then move on to overriding Flexform.

Override the label of the first item ("Default" => 0) in a list of items for the field "layout" in the table "tt_content".

Note, that here we are using the value to reference the item. In our example, it is "0". In your example, it seems to be "value".

```
# TCEFORM.<tablename>.<fieldname>.altLabels.<fielditem value>
TCEFORM.tt_content.layout.altLabels.0 = Hello!!!
```

You can now see, that the label of the first item has been changed to "Hello!!!":

[image]

##### Example 2: Do this for Flexform

I think your example should look something like this (is hard to tell though because of incomple flexform missing the field name).

```
# TCEFORM.<tablename>.pi_flexform.<plugin signature>.<sheet><field name with escaped dots (by backslash)>.altLabels.<item value>
TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.txhtest_pi1.myfield.altLabels.value = New Title
```

##### What is wrong in the snippet in the question

- missing sheet name (as already pointed out)
- possibly missing dots in field name in flexform
- possibly wrong "plugin signature": this is a combination of the extension key and the plugin key, all in lowercase, separated by an underscore, so for example "powermail_pi1", see also [Naming Conventions](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/BestPractises/NamingConventions.html), so I think here the extension key without underscore must be used (contrary to the TCA docs, should check this to make sure ...)
- trying to override using the language key

Note that both the usage of the extension key (either with or without underscores or with all-lowercase etc) and what you override how in TCA with TSConfig can be very confusing and seems to make no logical sense at all (until at some point you understand it, sometimes not even then). Sorry.

##### Documentation / References

The documentation for [altLabels](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/main/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html#altlabels) even has a Flexform example:

```
Flex form field level, example:
  TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.my_ext_pi1.sDEF.myField.altLabels = ...
```

So it is:

```
TCEFORM.<tablename>.pi_flexform.>pluginsignation>.<sheetname>.<field name with escaped dots (by backslash)>.altLabels = ...
```

Additionally, Torben Hansen has written a blog post, which is also quite helpful:

- "[How to extend existing FlexForm select options of a TYPO3 plugin using Page TSconfig](https://www.derhansen.de/2020/11/typo3-extend-existing-flexform-select-options.html)" (Nov 16, 2020)